# Installing mod-wsgi in centos7 via pip3 throws "ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1"

Tags: python-3.x, pip, mod-wsgi

Below is the error occurred on installing mod-wsgi using pip tool.

[root@localhost ~]# pip3 install mod-wsgi

```
Collecting mod-wsgi   Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/a0/8b/34dd82c3e15a031e9c89f5a5d2ca527ec35b7a01e1e7530abb61ffdb4d60/mod_wsgi-4.7.0.tar.gz (497kB)
     |████████████████████████████████| 501kB 111kB/s 
    ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
     command: /usr/local/bin/python3.6 -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/tmp/pip-install-72ufrkfx/mod-wsgi/setup.py'"'"';
__file__='"'"'/tmp/pip-install-72ufrkfx/mod-wsgi/setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' egg_info --egg-base /tmp/pip-install-72ufrkfx/mod-wsgi/pip-egg-info
         cwd: /tmp/pip-install-72ufrkfx/mod-wsgi/
    Complete output (5 lines):
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
      File "/tmp/pip-install-72ufrkfx/mod-wsgi/setup.py", line 168, in <module>
        'missing Apache httpd server packages.' % APXS)
    RuntimeError: The 'apxs' command appears not to be installed or is not executable. Please check the list of prerequisites in the documentation for this package and install any missing Apache httpd server packages.
    ---------------------------------------- ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: python setup.py egg_info Check the logs for full command output.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a system requirement details given in the official mod-wsgi install page - https://pypi.org/project/mod-wsgi/

Since my system is centos7, I install below packages for fixing the issue.

```
yum install httpd httpd-devel -y
```

[root@localhost ~]# pip3 install mod-wsgi

```
Collecting mod-wsgi
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/a0/8b/34dd82c3e15a031e9c89f5a5d2ca527ec35b7a01e1e7530abb61ffdb4d60/mod_wsgi-4.7.0.tar.gz
Installing collected packages: mod-wsgi
    Running setup.py install for mod-wsgi ... done
Successfully installed mod-wsgi-4.7.0
```